# URL rewrite not working nee to change (/blog/category/) to (/)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, nopcommerce

On web config I had written the following code as

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="catalogsmain" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="\/blog\/category\/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Also Tried

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="catalogsmain" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
          <match url="/blog/category/" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
        </rule>        
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

And when I am browsing the url as 
http://localhost:55390/blog/category/healthy-living-and-advice

It is not changing to

http://localhost:55390/healthy-living-and-advice

**How can I rewrite the url ?**

I want to change

http://mitesh.com/blog/category/healthy-living-and-advice

to

http://mitesh.com/healthy-living-and-advice

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the part of the url behind `blog/category`
Also I'm not sure wether the url does contain a slash at the start. So try this

```
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="catalogsmain" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="\/?blog\/category\/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The question mark in the regex is just there because I'm not sure about the slash. But the principle is you capture one part of your url and `{R:1}` is a reference to the contents of the first capture group.